# Print only 5 line of each having 32 chars using Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

How to print only 5 line of each having 32 chars using Freemarker. Currently i have the below solution. Is there any better way of doing using split or substring

```
      <#assign msg="Tell FreeMarker to convert string to real date-time value Convert date-time value to date-only value Let FreeMarker format it according the date_format setting">
      <#assign len=msg?length>
      <#list 1..5 as i>
         <#assign start=(i-1)*32>
         <#assign end=i*32>
           <#if (end <len)>   
${msg[start..end]}
           <#else>
${msg[start..len-1]}
           </#if>
       </#list>
```

result is

```
Tell FreeMarker to convert string
g to real date-time value Convert
t date-time value to date-only va
alue Let FreeMarker format it acc
cording the date_format setting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<#list msg?matches(".{1,32}")[0..*5] as row>
  ${row}
</#list>
```

Note that the "length limited range" operator, `..*`, doesn't give error if the length is less than what you asked for. So even with your approach, you can remove the `end` assignment and the `#if/#else`, and just use `${msg[start..*32]}`.

Comment: great!. Thanks :)